# When is the onPreExecute called on an AsyncTask running parallely or concurrently?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using Android HoneyComb.I need to execute some tasks parallely and I am using AsyncTask's
**public final AsyncTask executeOnExecutor (Executor exec, Params... params)** method.In each separate thread I am computing some values and I need to store then in an ArrayList.I must then sort all the values in the arrayList and then display it in the UI.Now my question is if one of the thread gets completed earlier than the other then will it immediately call the **onPostExecute** method or  **onPostExecute** method will be called after all the background threads have been completed?MY program implementation depends on what occurs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though using onexecuteExecutor will give you parallel execution, postexecute will be called by each asynctask as soon as it's finished.

But the asynctask will return itself so that you can know which is which if necessary and track their return order.

[The doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29)

As for managing an arraylist from multiple threads, I think you should take a look at Vectors as they are synchronized with a fail-fast behavior. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Answer (score 3):

Now..... its this way...

`AsyncTask` synchronized the UI thread, and the Output of the Non-UI work on the Non-UI thread.

`onPreExecute()` is called on the `UI thread`, **before the Non-UI work starts**.

Then `doInBackground()` **executes** spinning the Non-UI thread, at this time `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` keeps **executing simultaneously.... but its highly unpredicatble about its execution.**

**After** the `doInBackground(`), the `onPostExecute()` **runs on the UI Thread.**

**See this link for further details:**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I understood that?but my question is do onPostExecute() waits for all the parallel threads to complete?

Comment: @Debarshi Dutta `onPostExecute()` will wait only for `doInBackground()` of that `AsynTask`, and not for any other AsyncTask or any other thread out of it....

Comment: so what happens when I use the executoronExecutor method?and suppose I use two runnables?will the onpostExecute run two times?

Comment: Then main purpose of using AsyncTask here isto give Painless Threading experience to the programmer, if you want to use Executors, then again remember its a Non-UI thread for the Non-UI task, then you will need a Handler to sync it with the Dedicated UI thread, this kills the whole purpose of using AsyncTask....